# Lifetime of the epoll_ctl() event parameter

Tags: c, linux, epoll

The [`man` page for `epoll_ctl()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html) gives this signature:

```
int epoll_ctl(int epfd, int op, int fd, struct epoll_event *event);
```

Should the `epoll_event` parameter be saved until we are finished all the `epoll_wait()` processing?

In other words, is this code based on [`epoll` man page sample](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) correct?

```
int listen_sock, nfds, epollfd;

/* Code to set up listening socket, 'listen_sock', (socket(), bind(), listen()) omitted. */
epollfd = epoll_create1(0);
if (epollfd == -1) {
    perror("epoll_create1");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

{
    /* limit ev's scope */
    struct epoll_event ev;
    ev.events = EPOLLIN;
    ev.data.fd = listen_sock;
    if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, listen_sock, &ev) == -1) {
        perror("epoll_ctl: listen_sock");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

struct epoll_event events[MAX_EVENTS];
nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think epoll_event  don't need to be saved until we are finished all the epoll_wait() processing
because linux use copy_from_user as soon as you call systemcall `epoll_ctl`

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE4(epoll_ctl, int, epfd, int, op, int, fd,
        struct epoll_event __user *, event)
{
    struct epoll_event epds;

    if (ep_op_has_event(op) &&
        copy_from_user(&epds, event, sizeof(struct epoll_event)))
        return -EFAULT;

    return do_epoll_ctl(epfd, op, fd, &epds, false);
}
```

detail here : https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/eventpoll.c#L2176